# How can I cancel a kotlin coroutine job in onStop() method

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)


        scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
        job = scope.async {

            Log.e("TAG", "enter")
            while (isActive) {
                Log.e("TAG", "$isActive   Do something")
            }
        }

    }

override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        job.cancel()
    }
```

I need to do some infinite loops in the job, and I want to cancel the job when this Activity closes.

So I try to use `job.cancel` in onStop() method . But the loops continue, Still output "true, do something "

I knew it can be replaced by Thread or a ThreadPool, but is there any way to solve it by kotlin coroutine

Comment: You should use `launch` instead of `async` for a fire-and-forget coroutine like this. Maybe it helps with the cancellation too.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work.